# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user but the user is not on that machine

Tags: python, database, psycopg2

I have a database of mine on a remote server on which I'm trying to connect (operation that goes like a charm on DBeaver).
If I try to connect to it via psycopg2, though, via a script, I'm getting

```
[...]
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "gimmi"
```

In the remote machine, there is no such user as "gimmi" (which is the one on my local machine). What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

In your connect string add the ", user=your_user" parameter. Presume your local machine efault user is "gimme" so you need to specifically define the user

Comment: My connect string is currently like this conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='gimmi' user='gimmi' password=pass host=hosting port=port) but it won't get through

Comment: But you have written "In the remote machine, there is no such user as "gimmi"". If there's no such user why do you have it in your connect string? You need to specify some valid user, perhaps "postgres", that exists on the remote machine DB

Comment: yeah sorry, postgres was the one specified not "gimmi", it was my bad